# VB.NET: Thread-join never returns?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

my problem is that in a WCF service (on a network call) the thread doesn't come back. Unfortunately, I don't get any return values for functions or code after the join method is not executed.
The WCF service itself has a web interface that creates a thread because a form with TreeView and AllowDrop activated there would later return an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "DragDrop registration failed"
ThreadStateException: STA mode (Single Thread Apartment) must be set for the current thread before OLE calls can be made. Make sure that the main function is marked with STAThreadAttribute.
```

If, on the other hand, I start a sample project "WindowsApp56" (no WCF service), Form1 is opened by ClassLibrary7 and code according to the join method is activated. The message box "ready" is now displayed.

No errors are thrown with the web service, when the thread isn't coming back.

Project WindowsApp56:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports ClassLibrary7

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tmp As New Class1
        Dim myobject As System.Threading.Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf tmp.Main))
        myobject.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        myobject.Name = "Tester1"
        myobject.Start()
        If myobject.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Unstarted Then
            myobject.Join()
        End If
        MsgBox("ready")
    End Sub
End Class
```

ClassLibrary7:

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim a As New Form1
        a.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is the thread join method wrong? How can I "wait for" return values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message: 'STA mode (Single Thread Apartment) must be set for the current thread before OLE calls can be made. Make sure that the main function is marked with STAThreadAttribute.'

Add the STAThreadAttribute attribute on the Main method.

```
Public Class Class1
    <STAThread()>
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim a As New Form1
        a.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```